# Webcam sometimes stops working until next reboot when using Microsoft Teams

Tags: 20.04, webcam, microsoft

I'm using Microsoft Teams on Ubuntu MATE 20.04, installed via the deb from the website. Sometimes the webcam will stop working and certain things break within Teams - it won't show me new people, allow me to hang up, etc. It's a Logitech C920 webcam and doesn't use any proprietary drivers or any of that nonsense.

Restarting Teams fixes these issues, but doesn't bring the webcam back. Once it's gone, there's no sign of the webcam on the system - no other applications can see it and there's no `/dev/video0` (or `video1` - normally there is, even if `ffplay` won't do anything with it). Unplugging the webcam and plugging it back in again doesn't fix this (same port or a different port) but rebooting the computer does.

When shutting down the computer, it hangs on `systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: pulseaudio`. No clue if this is causation or correlation.

I've done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> within Teams to get some logs, but they don't tell me a great deal and it doesn't seem like a great idea to go and upload them in their entirety somewhere. But if there's anything in there of use, I have it available.